# Need to return file path from function and pass it as argument to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The path of the chosen file (stored in variable `source_file`) must be returned from `browseFiles()` and passed as argument to  `objdetect()`.

```
def browseFiles():
   source_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File", filetypes =[('All Files', '.*')],parent=window)
   label_file_explorer.configure(text=""+source_file)
```

Python 3.8 (Tkinter)
[Project details](https://github.com/Surveillance-NWB/Surveillance/blob/main/Surveillance.NWB.py)

Comment: Okay. And what's your problem or question?

Comment: `return source_file` seems to be the answer to your question. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach:

```py
def browseFiles():
   source_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File", filetypes =[('All Files', '.*')],parent=window)
   label_file_explorer.configure(text=""+source_file)
   return source_file


def objdetect()
    file = browseFiles()
```

Basically just use `return` statement to return a value and then assign that function to a variable and it will be called and the returned value will be assigned to the variable

If you simply want to have a global value you can do this:

```py
def browseFiles():
   global source_file
   source_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select a File", filetypes =[('All Files', '.*')],parent=window)
   label_file_explorer.configure(text=""+source_file)
```

Now the variable `source_file` will be global and you can reference it wherever you need

Comment: There is a main function that invokes both `browseFiles()` and `objdetect()`. As per your suggestion, I understand that `browseFiles()` function will be executed again.  I simply want to use the value saved in `source_file` without the calling the function.  Is there any way to do it?

Comment: @KavyaPriya ok, well then just add global, I will update